# HashTag Not Working To Show Div When URL Has ?source= Added

Tags: jquery, fancybox-2, hashtag, window.location, deep-linking

I am firing up FancyBox2 with incoming HashTags.  It all works... until you add a source code to the URL.  How can I get this to work?  Below is the code.  I am assuming I need to say hash=everything up until a ? if a ? exist.

Jquery:

```
var thisHash = window.location.hash;
if(window.location.hash) {
$(thisHash).fancybox().trigger('click');
}
```

Links that need to work:

www.mysite.com/test/#test - this works

www.mysite.com/test/#test?source=blahblahblah - this does not

www.mysite.com/test/?source=blahblahblah#test - this works lol

Answer (score 2):

**Quick answer:** The hash tags / named anchors / fragment identifiers (how ever you call them) must come *after* the query string to be parsed properly (at least as you expect them to be). **So you need to build your URLs accordingly**.

The following question on superuser.com has a full answer for your question (albeit your question is a bit different, the answer is the same) :

[Does an anchor tag come before the query string or after?](https://superuser.com/questions/498617/does-an-anchor-tag-come-before-the-query-string-or-after)

Although `http://www.example.com/test/#test?source=blahblahblah` is a valid URL, what will be considered as the hash tag string is the whole `test?source=blahblahblah` part (with no query string being detected). Also, if you need to include the `#` char in the path, document or query string parts of the URL it must be endoded as `%23`.

So no, your second link will never work as you intend it to be, even if you need it to work like that.

**EDIT - Bonus**

If you're looking for an easy way to add a query string to an existing url in PHP, try `url_add_query_params()` from the following code:

```
 function build_query($query_data, $numeric_prefix = '', $arg_separator = '&', $inner_call = 0) {
    // Source: http://php.net/manual/en/function.http-build-query.php#112024
    if (!is_array($query_data)) return false;
    $result = array();
    foreach ((array)$query_data as $key => $value) {
        if ($inner_call) {
            if (is_numeric($key))
                $key = $numeric_prefix . "[]";
            else
                $key = $numeric_prefix . "[$key]";
        } else {
           if (is_int($key))
                $key = $numeric_prefix . $key;
        }

        if (is_array($value) || is_object($value)) {
            $result[] = build_query($value, $key, $arg_separator, 1);
                continue;
        }
        $result[] = urlencode($key) . "=" . urlencode($value);
    }
    return implode($arg_separator, $result);
}

function unparse_url($parsed_url) {
      // Source: http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php#106731
      $scheme   = isset($parsed_url['scheme']) ? $parsed_url['scheme'] . '://' : '';
      $host     = isset($parsed_url['host']) ? $parsed_url['host'] : '';
      $port     = isset($parsed_url['port']) ? ':' . $parsed_url['port'] : '';
      $user     = isset($parsed_url['user']) ? $parsed_url['user'] : '';
      $pass     = isset($parsed_url['pass']) ? ':' . $parsed_url['pass']  : '';
      $pass     = ($user || $pass) ? "$pass@" : '';
      $path     = isset($parsed_url['path']) ? $parsed_url['path'] : '';
      $query    = isset($parsed_url['query']) ? '?' . $parsed_url['query'] : '';
      $fragment = isset($parsed_url['fragment']) ? '#' . $parsed_url['fragment'] : '';
      return "$scheme$user$pass$host$port$path$query$fragment";
}

function url_add_query_params($url, $new_params) {
    // parse url
    $url_components = parse_url($url);
    // return immediately if parsing failed
    if ($url_components === FALSE) { return $url; }
    // if $new_params is a query string, parse it
    if (!is_array($new_params)) {
        $new_params_str = $new_params;
        $new_params = array();
        parse_str($new_params_str, $new_params);
    }
    // parse query string from original url
    $params_str = isset($url_components['query']) ? $url_components['query'] : '';
    $params = array();
    parse_str($params_str, $params);
    // merge the two arrays, keeping later values for identical keys
    $params = array_merge($params, $new_params);
    // rebuild query string
    $url_components['query'] = build_query($params);
    // rebuild url
    return unparse_url($url_components);
}
```

Example:

```
$url = 'http://www.example.com/test/#test';
$new_url = url_add_query_params($url, 'source=blahblahblah');
echo $new_url; // output: http://www.example.com/test/?source=blahblahblah#test
echo "\n";

$url = 'http://www.example.com/test/?source=index&param=value#test';
$new_url = url_add_query_params($url, 'source=blahblahblah');
echo $new_url; // output: http://www.example.com/test/?source=blahblahblah&param=value#test
```

I only lightly tested it, but it should work as intended.

Comment: Thanks for the post - I get what your saying and it being proper (which I will now follow), but I would imagine that you could write code to look for a #Hash and stop once you reach a ?mark. Then take that string and fire off the according FacnyBox.  I would imagine you need to use RegEx with jQuery.  Therefore treating the Hash a bit differently then just as a Hash.

Comment: The problem with that is, even if you patch/fix jQuery, browsers and HTTP servers will style behave the same, i.e. any query parameters after the "#" will be stripped from requests (and be part of the fragment identifier instead). And I'm sure you don't want to write your own browser or server.

Answer (score 2):

The reason why this `www.mysite.com/test/#test?source=blahblahblah` link doesn't work is because the variable :

```
var thisHash = window.location.hash
```

... will return `#test?source=blahblahblah`.

Then you are trying to bind `thisHash` (`#test?source=blahblahblah`) to fancybox

```
$(thisHash).fancybox().trigger('click');
```

... which is an **invalid** selector.

You may need to write a function that validates `window.location.hash` and extracts the proper selector to be bound to fancybox like :

```
var _param;
function getSelector(thisHash) {
    if (thisHash.indexOf("?")) {
        _param = thisHash.split("?");
        return _param[0];
    } else {
        return thisHash;
    };
};
```

Check these jsfiddle links :

- http://jsfiddle.net/30p81gon/show/#test
- http://jsfiddle.net/30p81gon/show/#test?source=blahblahblah

Then you could bind fancybox to the proper selector and add the trailing parameter `"?source="` on the fly like :

```
var thisHash = window.location.hash;
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
    if (window.location.hash) {
        var selector = getSelector(thisHash);
        $(selector).fancybox({
            beforeLoad: function () {
                this.href = this.href + (typeof _param == "undefined" ? "" : "?" + _param[1])
            }
        }).trigger('click');
    }
}); // ready
```

Comment: what if the URL is www.mysite.com/?sourecode#HashTag.  Won't the above code cause this not to work then?

Comment: I answered for the none-working link, but I bet you pretty much got the idea what's going on and how to solve it, didn't you? (unless you want me to write the full recipe)